# raspberry pi 3 model B+ acting weird during startup

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot

So I found my old pi while cleaning, I flashed a fresh copy of raspbian on the SD, booted up the pi but for some reason it is exhibiting a weird behavior. Not as experienced with these so i am not too sure what to start with.[image]

Comment: It says "ext-fs4" error, which is the file system on the memory card. Try with another memory card and see if the error persists.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use class 10 type (good quality) SD card and use [this](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) for flashing the image.

Verify the version of Raspbian OS with RPi board revision and flash that OS.

Comment: An answer should not need interaction with the questioner, e.g. to answer questions. An answer is an answer is an answer, not a question or comment to clarify.